# get specific attribute xml java

Tags: java, xml, nodelist

I am trying to read this xml file, and I am only interested in Item Name="PubDate" attribute.

```
<eSummaryResult>
<DocSum>
<Id>23373820</Id>
<Item Name="PubDate" Type="Date">2013 Mar</Item>
<Item Name="EPubDate" Type="Date">2013 Feb 1</Item>
<Item Name="Source" Type="String">Expert Opin Emerg Drugs</Item>
<Item Name="AuthorList" Type="List">...</Item>
<Item Name="LastAuthor" Type="String">Rascol O</Item>
<Item Name="Title" Type="String">...</Item>
<Item Name="Volume" Type="String">18</Item>
<Item Name="Issue" Type="String">1</Item>
<Item Name="Pages" Type="String">39-53</Item>
<Item Name="LangList" Type="List">...</Item>
<Item Name="NlmUniqueID" Type="String">101135662</Item>
<Item Name="ISSN" Type="String">1472-8214</Item>
<Item Name="ESSN" Type="String">1744-7623</Item>
<Item Name="PubTypeList" Type="List">...</Item>
<Item Name="RecordStatus" Type="String">PubMed - indexed for MEDLINE</Item>
<Item Name="PubStatus" Type="String">ppublish+epublish</Item>
<Item Name="ArticleIds" Type="List">...</Item>
<Item Name="DOI" Type="String">10.1517/14728214.2013.766168</Item>
<Item Name="History" Type="List">...</Item>
<Item Name="References" Type="List"/>
<Item Name="HasAbstract" Type="Integer">1</Item>
<Item Name="PmcRefCount" Type="Integer">2</Item>
<Item Name="FullJournalName" Type="String">Expert opinion on emerging drugs</Item>
<Item Name="ELocationID" Type="String">doi: 10.1517/14728214.2013.766168</Item>
<Item Name="SO" Type="String">2013 Mar;18(1):39-53</Item>
</DocSum>
</eSummaryResult>
```

when my programs goes through the following code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbPub = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
              DocumentBuilder db2 = dbPub.newDocumentBuilder();
              url1 = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=23373820";
              Document docPmid = db2.parse(new URL(url1).openStream());                                 
             NodeList nl = docPmid.getElementsByTagName("Item");
             if(nl !=null && nl.getLength() > 0)
             {
               for (int y = 0; y < nl.getLength(); y++)
               {
                 Element el = (org.w3c.dom.Element) nl.item(y);
                 if (el.hasAttribute("Name") && el.getAttribute("Name").equals("PubDate"))
                 {
                   String pubDate = el.getAttribute("Name");
                   System.out.println("PubDate :"+pubDate);
                 }
               }
             }
```

Instead of getting PubDate :2013 Mar 
I get PubDate :PubDate

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35261456/edit) and include the whole XML file.

Comment: What you want `String pubDate = el.getAttribute("Name");` will do? You want something else I'd say ;-)

Comment: You need to read the content of that element, not one of it's attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just overlooked...

You are using the same in if

```
if (el.hasAttribute("Name") && el.getAttribute("Name").equals("PubDate"))
```

and later the same for printing:

```
String pubDate = el.getAttribute("Name");
System.out.println("PubDate :"+pubDate);
```

which is probably not what you want to do, you want to read the content, not the attribute value...

Answer (score 0):

In this XML line

```
<Item Name="PubDate" Type="Date">2013 Mar</Item>
```

you have an element called 'Item', that has two attributes:

- Name='PubDate'
- Type='Date'

and a value, that is "2013 Mar".

In your code, in line:

```
String pubDate = el.getAttribute("Name");
```

you ask for a value of the attribute called 'Name', which is in fact 'PubDate'.

What you want to do is to find an 'Item' element, that's 'Name' attribute is equal to 'PubDate' and then get its value with 'getNodeValue()' function.